# custom filter for radio check using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to check the `radio` button only if the **defaultValue** became true. Without going to function, is any other angular magic to check the radio button on UI. Here my `json` sturcture and `html` code.

```
 $scope.option = { "optionValues": [
        {
          "id": 2159,
          "name": "Soup",
          "price": 0,
          "defaultValue": true
        },
        {
          "id": 2160,
          "name": "Salad (dressing?)",
          "price": 0,
          "defaultValue": false
        }
      ]}

<table class="table">
   <tr ng-repeat="values in option.optionValues">
      <td><input type="radio" name="value" ng-model="values.name" ng-value="values.name">{{values.name}}</td>
      <td>{{values.price | currency}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the radio input top be checked You should have the following an ng-model in your template:

```
 <input type="radio" name="value.name" ng-value="true" ng-model="values.defaultValue">
```

Comment: Is possible to use filter or condition within a `ng-model`?

Comment: sorry, my bad, check updated code - ng-value="true" ng-model="values.defaultValue", http://plnkr.co/edit/mPnzUFvdqjzhQx7NoCND?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. Within the same process, is possible to change all the `defaultValue` as false except the selected radio option while changes occur.